# text-align beneath multiple images

Tags: html, css, image

I have four images that are horizontally placed next to each other. I am trying to put text beneath each of those images. This is what I have right now.

**HTML**

```
<div class="team">
<h3>Our Team</h3>
<img src="image.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" hspace="20" /> <h3>John Doe</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<img src="image.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" hspace="20" /> <h3>John Doe</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<img src="image.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" hspace="20" /> <h3>John Doe</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<img src="image.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" hspace="20" /> <h3>John Doe</h3>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

> .team {
>       display: block;
>       float:bottom;
>       padding: 10px;
>       margin: 15px;
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to wrap each one of those in a div tag that has the style "display:inline-block;" - like this:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" hspace="20" /> 
    <br><h3>John Doe</h3>  
    <br><p>Text</p>  
    <br><p>Text</p> 
</div>        
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" hspace="20" /> 
    <br><h3>John Doe</h3>  
    <br><p>Text</p>  
    <br><p>Text</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float: bottom ??

You need 4 separate divs floated left next to each other, contained in a parent div if you want centered. Simple.

```
<div class="left">img,p</div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    Float: left;
    //add padding and margins
}
```

That's what you need. Can't write it all out for you, it's exhausting on an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want it: http://jsbin.com/welcome/8969